# getting row from Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, datatable

I've got the following datatable with the following sql - statement:

```
SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand("Select route.rowid,route.route_id,start.name,folgenummer from haltestelle_route route join haltestellen start on start.id = route.haltestelle_id where route_id = '" + dlRoute.SelectedValue + "'", conSQLiteDb);
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(com);
            dthalte = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dthalte);
            GVRoute.DataSource = dthalte;
            GVRoute.DataBind();
            lbAdd.Visible = true;
```

and my datatable is global, and i wann delete all rows from this table in the database and after this i wanna insert all again and add a new row(this row is created by the user) in the middle of the table. For example my table looks like this:
(id,name)

```
1 stefan
2 david
3 christian
```

and i wanna delete all rows and after this get this

```
1 stefan
2 gregor
3 david
4 christian
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements.  Why are you wanting to delete everything from the table then add everything back again?  Also, use Parameterised SQL.

Comment: i thought this was the easiest way...

Comment: Is the goal to add the record to the table at a specific identity?  If so, that somewhat defeats the purpose of SQL.  I would suggest adding another column for a 'sort order' or similar if that is the case.

Comment: Yeah something like this.

Comment: there is a number for every name and if the user wants to add a new one at position 2 all the other from postion 2 to max length have to get a new number....and after this i have to insert all rows again including the new one....is there any way to create this easily?